# Use Stylesheet to Convert Excel Data to XML

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

Is there a way to create a kind of "template" in Excel (2010) to take in data in one or more spreadsheets, and then convert that data to XML, based on an XML schema?  Or any similar features in Excel?

I know there are several XML features in Excel but haven't found how to do what I want to do above.

Answers and comments appreciated.

Comment: for simple XML dump just select save as type -> `XML Spreadsheet *.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did something similar quite some time ago. Might not be exactly what you want but should hopefully get you started in the right direction.

- First enable the Developer tab in the ribbon. A simple google search should tell you how to do that.
- In the Developer tab, click on 'Import' button (in the 'XML' subtab). This should let you import an existing XML (data) file. This imports data as a table with appropriate column names. This would be your 'template'.
- Now you can add/modify rows to this table and once done, right click (within the table) and use XML->Export in the context menu.

Been a long time but remember facing issues with more complex XML files (multiple one-to-may relations or something) so this approach might be good only for relatively simple XML schemas (unless you combine this with an XSL transform).

Comment: Thanks, I found this just as you answered.  You are right that simple schemas (or consolidated, single schemas in lieu of multiple references) work best.  I couldn't get multiple schemas working, but could get a single one to work.  Excellent :)